# Probability, counting. Die toss problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fair die is played 3 times. Let X be the sum throws of the die and Y the remainder when X divided by 4 (i.e. Y can be 0,1,2 or 3). Find the distribution of Y, its mean and variance.

Im having a lot of trouble trying to figure out, any idea or suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: start by finding the four probabilities for the four possible values of Y.  
Y = 0   for sums of 4, 8, 12, 16   ---   
Y = 1  for sums of 5, 9, 13, 17   ---  
---
etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, evaluate the distribution of $X$

$\mathsf P(X=4) = \dfrac{3}{6^3}$ etc.

Then combine to obtain that of $Y$.

$\mathsf P(Y=0) = \mathsf P(X \in\{4,8,12,16\}) = \mathsf P(X=4)+\mathsf P(X=8)+\mathsf P(X=12)+\mathsf P(X=16)$

$\mathsf P(Y=1) = \mathsf P(X \in\{5,9,13,17\})$

$\mathsf P(Y=2) = \mathsf P(X \in\{6,10,14,18\})$

$\mathsf P(Y=3) = \mathsf P(X \in\{3,7,11,15\})$